# How to choose dynamicly in C/C++ the type to cast to?

Tags: c++, c, casting

Is there a way to do

```
if(...)
  return (char)value;

return (unsigned char)value;
```

by moving the check into the cast to get something like

```
return (???)value;
```

The goal is to interprete the content of value differently
eg: (unsigned char)144=>144 and (char)144=>-112

Comment: There is no "C/C++" language: please pick one.

Comment: No.............. A function returns the type you stated in the function prototype, e.g. `ReturnType foo();`

Comment: `return ... ? static_cast<int>(value) : static_cast<unsigned>(value);`. All you need after that is a `variant<int, unsigned>` for the return type

Comment: What is the type of `value`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? what is the problem you are trying to solve with variant return type

Comment: I would return a std::variant<int, unsigned int>

Comment: @Eliyahu Machluf I'm trying to change the range of a value, eg (unsigned char)144 ==144, but (char)144 ==-112

Comment: @guigoz I think it's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you could edit the code so it shows a complete function and shows how you want to call it. BTW: `char` isn't always signed...

Comment: 0b10010000 can be either 144 or -122 when casted, that's what I want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

No, in both C and C++ the return type of a function is fixed, i.e. it will always return the same type. Even if you try to cast as part of the `return` statement, the returned value will implicit be converted to the return type of the function - if possible. If an implicit conversion ain't possible, you'll get a compile error.

So

```
returntype foo(...) {.... return x;}
```

will always return a value of type `returntype`

In C++ you can use templates to "change" return type but once the template definition is solved it's the same story. Cast won't change the real return type.

Comment: How about `auto` return type with C++14?

Comment: What about returning a single type that could contain either types? For example, in C++17, you can have `std::variant<int, unsigned>`

Comment: @scrutari Return type deduction is done at compile time.

Comment: @scrutari Based on the argument types it still results into exactly 1 type at compile time. With`if constexpr` you can change that type, though that is still a compile time feature

Comment: Actually what is needed is to change the interpretation of value, not to change te return type of the function